# unable to get perl pack to work in this case

Tags: perl, pack, unpack

I ran following code

```
$a=pack("H1H3", "1","abc");
$b=unpack("B*", $a);
print "Got $b \n";

C:\Users\a0875499\Documents>perl abc.pl
Got 000100001010101111000000
```

Output looks incorrect to me. There is an extra "0000" which shouldn't be present. I am looking for output to be "0001101010111100". Do you know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'H'` format for `pack()` assembles bytes, so if you supply an odd number of values it will pad out the last byte with a null nybble.

If I correctly understand what you want to achieve, you could do it with:

```
$a = pack("H4", "1abc");
```

or

```
$a = pack("H*", "1abc");
```

Comment: Thnx Grant, but I need not always have an even number of bytes, right? In such cases it means I have to pad with an extra byte?

Comment: You don't need to provide an even number of bytes - no padding required for odd number of bytes. Each hex digit (or "nybble") is half a byte (4 bits) of formatted output. If you provide an odd number of hex digits then pack will assume 4 zero bits to pad the last byte.